# Make pandas df in wide format and unconcatenate values to different columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot

sorry, I have a bit of a trouble explaining the problem in title

By accident we pivoted our Pandas Dataframe  to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,2], [1,2,1], [2,1,2], [2,2,2],[3,1,3]]),columns=['id', '3s', 'score'])

id   3s  score
1    1   2
1    2   1
2    1   2             
2    2   2                 
3    1   3
```

But we need to unstack this so df will look like this (the original version): The '3s' column 'unpivots' to the discrete set by 3 ordered columns with 0s and 1s, which add in order. So if we had `'3s'= 2` with `'score'= 2` the values will be `[1,1,0]` (2 out of 3 in order) in columns `['4','5','6']` (second set of 3s) for corresponding `id`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,0,1,0,0], [2,1,1,0,1,1,0], [3,1,1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan] ]),columns=['id', '1', '2','3','4','5','6'])

id   1   2   3   4   5   6
1    1   1   0   1   0   0
2    1   1   0   1   1   0      
3    1   1   1
```

Any help greatly appreciated! 
*(please save me)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
for gr in df.groupby('3s').groups:
    for i in range(1,4):
        df[str(i+(gr-1)*3)]=np.where((df['3s'].eq(gr))&(df['score'].ge(i)), 1,0)
df=df.drop(['3s', 'score'], axis=1).groupby('id').max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
   id  1  2  3  4  5  6
0   1  1  1  0  1  0  0
1   2  1  1  0  1  1  0
2   3  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you, much more stable solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
n = 3
df2 = df.reindex(index = df.index.repeat(n))
new_df = (df2.assign(score = df2['score'].gt(df2.groupby(['id','3s'])
                                                .id
                                                .cumcount())
                                         .astype(int),
                     columns = df2.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))
             .pivot_table(index = 'id',
                          values='score',
                          columns = 'columns',
                          fill_value = '')
             .rename_axis(columns = None)
             .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
   id    1    2    3  4  5  6
0   1  1.0  1.0  0.0  1  0  0
1   2  1.0  1.0  0.0  1  1  0
2   3  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

If you want you can use **`fill_value = 0`**

```
   id  1  2  3  4  5  6
0   1  1  1  0  1  0  0
1   2  1  1  0  1  1  0
2   3  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you! lightning fast, but somehow I get 400 columns :)